# C++ class method reimplementation

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to tell to the compiler that not compile a method of parent class, but compiles the same method in the child class?.
May be confusing my question, My app will be released in two versions: regular and demo.
In demo version I want to remove/reimplement a method from the base class (the base class is from a framework), so:

```
class FromLibrary
{
public:
   ...
   void addProperty (Property* p) 
   {
       Some stuff with property, is used to save in files, etc...
   }
   ...
};

class MyClass : public FromLibrary
{
   #ifdef DEMO
   void addProperty (Property* p) {};
   #endif    
};
```

Ok, it works, but maybe a cracker can change the method address to point to "FromLibrary::addProperty"

Note: "FromLibrary" is not a static/dynamic lib, but I don't want to modify it, to keep updated without modify my own version

Comment: `#ifndef DEMO` in the base `addProperty` so it only has "content" when compiled in non demo mode?

Comment: @John3136 "Note: "FromLibrary" is not a static/dynamic lib, but I don't want to modify it"

Comment: @immibis. In that case your comment is right ;-) Reason I missed it is logic. Question now reads "How can I modify my code without modifying my code"

Comment: Get an aggressive linker to discard unused code?

Comment: What is a cracker in this context?

Comment: A compiler will compile anything you tell it to compile. If you do not want a compiler to compile something, don't include it in the source code, or disable it, with `#ifdef`, etc...

Comment: Thanks guys, I will modify the library code to add #ifdef